# Insert static files literally into Jinja templates without parsing them

Tags: python, jinja2

I'm trying to insert file into a page using Jinja 2.6 using the `include` tag. This worked fine until I started using characters in the file that are reminiscent of the Jinja syntax, at which point it realized it couldn't parse them and bombed.

Short of going though the file and escaping all characters, what can I do to tell Jinja to just include the file as is?

Comment: To clarify, the external file is a set of mustache javascript templates that are being used in multiple places. I don't want to modify them - just include them as in the HTML source.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can define a function to load the text file and render it in the template:

```
import jinja2

def include_file(name):
    return jinja2.Markup(loader.get_source(env, name)[0])

loader = jinja2.PackageLoader(__name__, 'templates')
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
env.globals['include_file'] = include_file

def render():
    return env.get_template('page.html').render()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print render()
```

In the template, call it like this:

```
{{ include_file('file.txt') }}
```

Comment: Thanks... I was hoping there was a built in method or plugin that I'd missed, but I'll just go with this.

Comment: Hi, Alex I didn't get output while using your code because using some parameter are undefined.
"(loader.get_source(env, name)"
Can you explain in details.

Comment: How do I include the contents of `file.txt` if it is located in the parent directory of the directory `templates`? Is this possible? Using `{{ include_file('../file.txt') }}` returns the error `jinja2.exceptions.TemplateNotFound: ../file.txt`.

Answer (score 11):

If you are using Flask it can be written like this:

```
from jinja2 import Markup

...

app.jinja_env.globals['include_raw'] = lambda filename : Markup(app.jinja_loader.get_source(app.jinja_env, filename)[0])
```

And used like this:

```
{{ include_raw('js-inline/modernizr.min.js') }}
```

Path of the included file is relative to your template folder as for normal includes.

Comment: Note that you can't search outside of the templates directory.  If you really need to get out of it, you must set your template directory higher in the path, or add more to the template search path with a custom Jinja loader.

Answer (score 7):

Try putting the syntax in the other files in `{% raw %} {% endraw %}`

You can use jQuery if you dont want to edit the external files:
Make a dive to contain the content `<div id="contentoffile"></div>`

and use jquery to load the file : `$("#contentoffile").load("url to file")`  << the url can be relative

Comment: That works, but the point is that I don't want to modify the included files. They're external and being used in other places.

Comment: Thanks for the ajax tip... I'm trying to avoid the extra request, though. Don't see why I need do another roundtrip when the files are right there when the template is being rendered.

Answer (score 4):

Here's a solution in the form of a tag, which looks more like the standard "include" when you're writing templates. [(This is how I do it for a static site generator called Combine.)](https://github.com/dropseed/combine/blob/47e7c75ca74fc056c7169206732b7cc1e3256773/combine/jinja/include_raw.py)

```py
from jinja2 import nodes
from jinja2.ext import Extension
from jinja2 import Markup


class IncludeRawExtension(Extension):
    tags = {"include_raw"}

    def parse(self, parser):
        lineno = parser.stream.expect("name:include_raw").lineno
        template = parser.parse_expression()
        result = self.call_method("_render", [template], lineno=lineno)
        return nodes.Output([result], lineno=lineno)

    def _render(self, filename):
        return Markup(self.environment.loader.get_source(self.environment, filename)[0])

# Use the extension when setting up Jinja
your_jinja_env = jinja2.Environment(
    extensions=[IncludeRawExtension],
)
```

Functionally it's the same as other answers here, but I think it helps to keep the same `{%` syntax as the regular "include" tag.

```html
{% include "template.html" %}
{% include_raw "template.html" %}
```

Answer (score 2):

As an update to @Alex's answer, you can use Jinja's [`@contextfunction`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.contextfunction) decorator to remove some of the reliance on global variables.  The updated code would look like:

```
import jinja2                                                                                                                                                                                                  

@jinja.contextfunction                                                                                                                                                                                         
def include_file(ctx, name):                                                                                                                                                                                   
    env = ctx.environment                                                                                                                                                                                      
    return jinja2.Markup(env.loader.get_source(env, name)[0])                                                                                                                                                  


def main():                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    loader = jinja2.PackageLoader(__name__, 'templates')                                                                                                                                                       
    env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)                                                                                                                                                                    
    env.globals['include_file'] = include_file                                                                                                                                                                 

    env.get_template('page.html').render()                                                                                                                                                                     


if __name__ == '__main__':                                                                                                                                                                                     
    print main()
```

And just as before, call it from your template like:

```
{{ include_file('file.txt') }}
```

Comment: but you are not passing 'ctx' parameter from method?!?

Comment: The `@contextfunction` decorator supplies it.  [docs](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#jinja2.contextfunction)

Comment: When I am calling the function it throwing an error as one more parameter required ...