# Including plain text files with filtering

Tags: python, regex, jinja2

So, we've got text files which we want to include in the template, and these contain a lot of garbage that we'd like to filter out at the same time.

Let's say filtering should be more or less based on this:

```
with open(file) as f:
    data = f.read()
    result = re.findall('[^!]\s*(\w{4}[^pP]:[^\n]+\;)', data)
```

I've already seen this example:
[Insert static files literally into Jinja templates without parsing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767585/insert-static-files-literally-into-jinja-templates-without-parsing-them)

```
import jinja2

def include_file(name):
    return jinja2.Markup(loader.get_source(env, name)[0])

loader = jinja2.PackageLoader(__name__, 'templates')
env = jinja2.Environment(loader=loader)
env.globals['include_file'] = include_file

def render():
    return env.get_template('page.html').render()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print render()
```

The question is: what should be inside include_file function in my case?

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this...

```
def include_file(self, name):
    with open(file) as f:
        data = f.read()
        result = re.findall('[^!]\s*(\w{4}[^pP]:[^\n]+\;)', data)
    return jinja2.Markup(result)

env.globals['include_file'] = include_file
```

then your template would look like this...

```
{{ include_file('file.txt') }}
```

this article helps to explain globals a little more.

http://modular.math.washington.edu/home/wstein/www/home/bjarke/sage-4.4.4/local/LIB/python/site-packages/Jinja-1.2-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/docs/html/objects.html

Hope this helps!