# Include file from static folder in Flask template

Tags: flask, jinja2

How can I include "in-line" javascript in a Flask template for performance but keep the code in a separate file in the static folder for organization? Something like this is what I'm looking for.

```
<script>
{% include_from_static 'in-line.js' %}
</script>
```

This doesn't seem possible with the normal `include` directive and `url_for`. If I need a custom function for this, how do I go about writing it? (There's a [related example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9769454/1493867) on another thread, but I don't understand enough to adapt the code for this.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you can pass the root of your Flask project to `PackageLoader`. The downside will be that you must have to prefix each file to the `template` and `static` folder.

app.py

```
from flask import Flask
from jinja2 import Markup, PackageLoader, Environment


app = Flask(__name__)


def include_file(name):
    return Markup(loader.get_source(env, name)[0])


loader = PackageLoader(__name__, '')
env = Environment(loader=loader)
env.globals['include_file'] = include_file


@app.route('/')
def index():
    return env.get_template('templates/page.html').render()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

---

static/script.js

```
console.log('hello world');
```

---

templates/page.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        {{ include_file('static/script.js') }}
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```