# Import text from external text file into html / jinja log report

Tags: python, html, import, jinja2

I would like to import text from an external text file into my html / jinja log report.

For this, I have the directory structure

```
│   main.py
│   requirements.txt
│
├───Output
│       log_report.html
│
├───templates
│       template.html
```

in which I run

```
from jinja2 import Template, DebugUndefined
from shutil import copyfile
import datetime
import getpass
import os
import socket


def log_start(file_name_template, file_name_log):

    copyfile(file_name_template, file_name_log)
    template = Template(open(file_name_log).read(), undefined=DebugUndefined)
    template_rendered = template.render(date_and_time=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S"),
                                        host_name=socket.gethostname(),
                                        user_name=getpass.getuser(),
                                        requirements="requirements.txt")
    return template_rendered


def main(output_dir="Output/",
         file_name_basis="log_report"):

    file_name_log = output_dir + file_name_basis + ".html"
    template_rendered = log_start("templates/template.html", file_name_log)
    with open(file_name_log, "w") as file_handle: file_handle.write(template_rendered)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

where `templates/template.html` consists of

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <body>
        <!-- Program execution information. -->
        <b>Program execution information.</b><br/>
        Date and time: {{date_and_time}}<br/>
        Host name: {{host_name}}<br/>
        User name: {{user_name}}<br/>
        Modules and their versions:<br/>
        {{requirements}}
    </body>
</html>
```

The code runs just fine like this. But instead of denoting `requirements.txt` in the final log report `log_report.html`, I want the contents of the file `requirements.txt` to be included in the final log report `log_report.html`.

I have considered the strategies as proposed at

https://www.dotnetcurry.com/html5/1167/read-local-file-api-html5-javascript

and

[Insert static files literally into Jinja templates without parsing them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9767585/insert-static-files-literally-into-jinja-templates-without-parsing-them)

but they look horrendous and extremely cumbersome to me for such a small action.

How do I tackle this problem in a nice, short and Pythonic manner?

Answer (score 2):

```
with open('file_path/filename_with_extension.txt', 'r') as f:
    requirements_txt = f.read() 

#for pass string var in your example
template_rendered = 
template.render(date_and_time=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d, %H:%M:%S"), 
host_name=socket.gethostname(), user_name=getpass.getuser(), 
requirements=requirements_txt )
```

Comment: Great simple and elegant answer. Though I think it contains one small mistake: the first line should be `with open('file_path/filename_with_extension.txt', 'r') as f:`. And an improvement would be to make a bulleted list from each line of text from `requirements.txt`. How to do this...

Comment: you can add this lines for add bullets before every line -- line = f.readline()                             
   while line:
       print( '&#8226;'  +  line)
       line = f.readline()